# Do the skulls and vases during the Hades fight count as enemies?

Tags: hades

The Demeter boon **Killing Freeze** grants the following benefit:

> When all foes are Chill affected, they are 12% slower and decay.

Fairly straight forward, except I'm not sure if the skulls and vases dropped by Hades during his boss fight count as enemies. I'm in a situation where the boon is really only worth grabbing if this is true, and since I'm sure I'll be in similar situations in the future, I was hoping to get a definite answer to this question.

I checked [the](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Demeter) [wiki](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Hades) but it didn't contain any relevant information. My google-fu is failing me as well.

Do the skulls and vases during the Hades fight count as enemies for the purposes of meeting the **Killing Freeze** "all foes are chill affected" trigger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I ended up grabbing this anyway since I didn't like any of my boon choices, so I can confirm that the skulls and vases ***do not*** count as enemies for the purposes of **Killing Freeze**

So during the second phase of the Hades fight having any amount of chill on Hades will result in him constantly  taking decay damage. During the first phase, he will summon regular and elite enemies in at certain health thresholds, which all need to be frozen for Hades to take the decay damage. The pots and skulls don't matter at all.